# creating a simple web page to ping ip address and show status

Tags: web

hello can anyone give me idea about how to make this scenario:
first of all i will create a txt file which contains ip addresses from a server extract by me ,
i want to create a web page something like the secreenshoot bellow , which  ping all IP address
and show status : up or down

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9JO.png)

any idea ?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

What language would you use to program your website ? In PHP you could use a function like this:

```
function ping($host, $SSL = true) {

  $fP = fSockOpen($host, $SSL ? 443 : 80, $errn, $err, 10); 
  if (!$fP) { return "down"; } 
  return "up"; 
}
```

This function will get a host and a boolean(SSL or not) as parameter and then return "down" if the host is not reachable on this port or "up" on the opposide.

Comment: yes i will use PHP , can you be more specific , thank you 
I would be grateful for your prompt reply with any doc or source to follow